# Skew line offset from cube center

Tags: geometry

How to find skew distance from the unit cube's ( of development below) center to straight line PQ in 3d?

[image]

Comment: I found distance of center from PQ. Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the cube on x-y plane with corners of base at $(\pm 0.5, \pm 0.5,0)$.

Center $C$ is at $(0,0,0.5)$.

$P = (0,0.5,1)$. $Q = (-0.5,-0.5,0.3)$

Then distance of $C$ from $QP$ is $$d=\dfrac{|QP \times CP|}{|QP|}$$

$QP=(0.5,1,0.7)$. $CP=(0,0.5,0.5)$

$$\Rightarrow d=\dfrac{|(0.15,-0.25,0.25)|}{\sqrt{1.74}}$$

$$\Rightarrow d \approx 0.2912$$